# jQuery .prepend a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, prepend

Hello Stack Overflow community! I would like to $("div").prepend(content), where content is a variable holding the user's input. I want the prepended text to be lime colored. Here is my CSS code:

```
p{
color:#00FF00;
}
```

But when I run it, it prepends the user's input like it was supposed to, but it wasn't lime color. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var content=prompt("Enter some text:");
$("div").prepend(content);
```

Any help would be appreciated! I am very new to JavaScript and jQuery. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The CSS has a type selector for `<p>` elements.

You are adding the content to a `<div>` element and the content you are adding, presumably, doesn't include any `<p>` elements.

Either change the selector in the stylesheet to match the element you are putting the content in, change that div into a p, or put a p element around the content.

Comment: What element am I putting in if I do $("div").prepend(content); and content is the variable containing the user's input?

Comment: @SkyLord52 — `$("div")` isn't going to select anything other than a div, is it?

Comment: @SkyLord52 — "content is the variable containing the user's input?" — well yes, that is what you wrote.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Now I have another question. This is what my div looks like on the webpage: This is my div. But when I enter the input, it prepends it in lime color, but it now looks like this: this is what I typed inThis is a div. It puts it right next to the div. How do I put the element that was .prepended above the div?